# sqlite encryption for android titanium Appcelerator

Tags: android, sqlite, encryption, appcelerator, titanium-android

Looking very hard for a possibility to encrypt my sqlite database on Android devices, but I wasn't able to find a satisfying solution.
I need something like a library to reference, in order to have a encryption/decryption of my database, while using the normal sqlite functions.
Or is there any other option like encrypt data before storing in db and decrypt it before using with help of any secret key.

In native android , there is Library [SQLCipher port to Android](https://guardianproject.info/code/sqlcipher/)

But I can't find any working example for this stuff.
Please help ThankYou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Appcelerator [Team plan](http://www.appcelerator.com/pricing/) gives you access to the official encryptedSql module. I don't know of any community versions, though you might encrypt the input with https://github.com/benbahrenburg/Securely before you write to SQL.